# cant run python code in terminal when trying to different commands

Tags: python, terminal

Im trying to run some python code in my terminal in vs code but i get errors when trying to run it. below is my code.

```
import string
from random import choice, shuffle

def randomPass():
    lower = list(string.ascli_lowercase)
    upper = list(string.ascli_uppercase)
    digits = list(string.digits)

    all = lower + upper + digits
    shuffle(all)

    length = int(input("How long is the password?: "))
    password = ''

    for i in range(length):
        password += choice(all)
        print(password)

    randomPass()
```

below is the errors i get when trying to run the code by using randomPass and How long is the password?: 10

[terminal errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STJi7.png)

Comment: Please note that it is ascii not ascli (line 5 and 6), also you need to remove the indentation for the last line.

Comment: FYI `all` is an inbuilt function in Python, try a different name.

Comment: This code has obvious errors.  As posted, it will not run.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Please post the error as text in a <pre></pre> tag, not as an image hosted on an external site.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with an indentation in your scripts:

```py
import string
from random import choice, shuffle


def randomPass():
    lower = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    upper = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    digits = list(string.digits)

    all = lower + upper + digits
    shuffle(all)

    length = int(input("How long is the password?: "))
    password = ""

    for i in range(length):
        password += choice(all)
    print(password)


randomPass()
```

Also if we refactor this:

```py
import string
from random import choice


def randomPass():
    lowercase = string.ascii_lowercase
    uppercase = string.ascii_uppercase
    digits = string.digits
    charset = lowercase + uppercase + digits

    length = int(input("How long is the password?: "))
    password = "".join(choice(charset) for _ in range(length))
    print(password)


randomPass()
```

Comment: How do i know where lines need to be indented to im sorry im new to python. thank you all for the help.

Comment: @M1guelp, you know where lines need to be indented by reading and understanding either the Python language specification or SO's markdown specification. Please understand that indentation is how Python defines blocks of code, it is paramount.

Comment: @MichaelRuth got it, ill look over some documentation. Didn't know it was important thank you for the help.

Comment: With each tab you increase the nesting level of the code, the more to the right it is, the more nested it is. If you want your `randomPass` method to contain code - write it 1 tab after `randomPass`. In this example, `randomPass` has no indent, so one tab is required (0 tabs + 1 tab) for its code. In the `randomPass` function, you have a loop that has code in it, so it's written 1 tab after the loop (1 tab for loop + 1 tab for its contents), and so on. `randomPass()` is written without tabs, because it is not nested anywhere, it sits by itself and is on the same nesting level as `randomPass`.

Comment: In your example, `print(password)` was in a for loop, so it fired every time the loop iterated, this line was directly in the body of the loop, and not to the `randomPass` function, so I removed one tab to return this line in the `randomPass` function so it be called after the loop. Next, the `randomPass()` line you had one tab after `randomPass`, i.e. was in the `randomPass` function directly, so your code did nothing.

Comment: The code execution goes from the outer level to the deepest.

**Also, keep in mind that in Python it is recommended by style to tabulate not with a tab character, but with spaces, which 100% cause more trouble if you're a newbie, but yeah, this is a style guide.**

You might wanna take a look at [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)